# Problem with alignment \paragraph heading

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have the Latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{section}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\theparagraph.}
{\wordsep}{}

\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{\wordsep}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph. San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph.
San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph. San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph.

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{35mm}
\fbox{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph. San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph.
San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph. San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph. San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph. San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph.
San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph. San Francisco is a city in California.  See paragraph.

\paragraph{}
San Francisco is a city in California. See paragraph
San Francisco is a city in California. See paragraph
San Francisco is a city in California. See paragraph.


\end{document}
```

And that gives me this view:

[image]

I've been trying to get the result as in the picture below, but I did not succeed. I ask for help

[image]

Comment: Select the code and hit Ctrl + K, or click the button marked `{}` above the text field, then it is marked up properly as code.

Comment: not directly related but `\paragraph` is a level  4 heading it is only intended to be used after `\subsubsection` but here you have it both after `\section` and after `\subsection`